# Bus error after calling recv()/ How to recieve chunked compressed data

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

Hi I have a simple browser that sends a request to yahoo.com which the server responds telling me 200 Ok and that it will send me a gzip file using encoded-transfer:chunked. Thats fine and all but when I run my program and continuously call recv(), I eventually run into a Bus Error. I'm not sure what that means at this point. Also I'm unclear how to read the header of the packet to tell me how many bytes it will send since the compressed file is in machine code. In this question I have included right bellow my code as well as the output that I see in terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define MAXDATASIZE 500;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
struct addrinfo serverSide,*serverInfo;
int mySock, status;
char buf[501],ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

memset(&serverSide, 0, sizeof serverSide);
serverSide.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
serverSide.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if(getaddrinfo("www.yahoo.com","80",&serverSide,&serverInfo)==0){

}

mySock = socket(serverInfo->ai_family, serverInfo->ai_socktype, serverInfo->ai_protocol);
connect(mySock, serverInfo->ai_addr, serverInfo->ai_addrlen);

char msg[500] = "GET http://www.yahoo.com HTTP/1.1\r\n";
strcat(msg,"Host: www.yahoo.com:80\r\n");
strcat(msg,"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1\r\n");
strcat(msg,"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n");
strcat(msg,"Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n");
strcat(msg,"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n");
strcat(msg,"Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n");
strcat(msg,"Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");

// I want to keep the code simple so I just call recv enough times to see what has been
// written to my buffer. If I could read the packet length in the header then I would 
// code in a while loop to adjust for that.
if((status = send(mySock,msg,strlen(msg),0))== -1){
printf("request not sent %d\n",status);
perror("\n");
}else{
if((status = recv(mySock, buf, 1500, 0))== -1){
printf("recieved byte error");
}else{
printf("%s",buf);
}
if((status = recv(mySock, buf, 1500, 0))== -1){
printf("recieved byte error");
}else{
printf("%s",buf);
}
if((status = recv(mySock, buf, 1500, 0))== -1){
printf("recieved byte error");
}else{
printf("%s",buf);
}
if((status = recv(mySock, buf, 1500, 0))== -1){
printf("recieved byte error");
}else{
printf("%s",buf);
}
}
close(mySock);
freeaddrinfo(serverInfo);
return 0;
}
```

Bellow is the output of my code. The server responds with the following...

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Sat, 21 Jan 2012 08:53:09 GMT Set-Cookie:
>   B=4peq6lh7hkv7l&b=3&s=u4; expires=Tue, 21-Jan-2014 20:00:00 GMT;
>   path=/; domain=.yahoo.com P3P:
>   policyref="http://info.yahoo.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADM
>   DEV TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi
>   IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC GOV"
>   Cache-Control: private X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Set-Cookie:
>   IU=deleted; expires=Fri, 21-Jan-2011 08:53:09 GMT; path=/;
>   domain=.yahoo.com Set-Cookie: PH=deleted; expires=Fri, 21-Jan-2011
>   08:53:09 GMT; path=/; domain=.yahoo.com Set-Cookie:
>   fpc=d=2BrdHmSMUw00.1uwnK1w8hHJcKnQt3UjRGxvUnBVIn0e6eAyRyd96eAPIN33Jne3IWoEE8r8eAk9xF0ExLsN5JJJmANZRlEBg8hpcDJ1GD7Gd50uZeP1H0_Wbf_mc.LJ45tDfhhwjR1BSedjT7AeGszK321i_gS34xKNuHlH2niKnP1lFG8y3aztEQsOkQHUu1w3zxk-&v=2;
>   expires=Sun, 20-Jan-2013 08:53:10 GMT; path=/; domain=www.yahoo.com
>   Set-Cookie: CH=deleted; expires=Fri, 21-Jan-2011 08:53:09 GMT; path=/;
>   domain=www.yahoo.com Set-Cookie:
>   CH=AgBPGnwQAA9AEAAA3RAAKY0QAAMPEAAYcxAAKN0QAD5XEAASNBAAJeoQACI8;
>   expires=Mon, 20-Feb-2012 08:53:09 GMT; path=/; domain=.yahoo.com
>   Set-Cookie:
>   fpt=d=nZFZlZHXecyEB3UWO0p6uOQtHkIdLjY734kqWOMHwg8Yq1e0sUpJBiMgYN63uaJ0.zEBsZIbeO93bfF0mXfQ8CtJYxAuet8CIS5PYmNMWfBDUU6ew8pXSI6cY3aX7Nk743wzRxbuCoBZGqvOM0eGhQMFOQ7BrCYBAZsAIYAOqwHKu7sNvbkPN7r0T7ncKpu5bX8LWPGngHHS97cCbNgpbgzOh13nP1m6.9cw7oPeudXdRjfzxsDUYqq2LvQJdECPWmccPhDEYfAoIl.Cfc8T8w_5.zrvoWG5kJr_T0megV4GtcTB324ZS2zkf0pi1GiMGYVHxGNh01c04XJnjk5q0ek_Xg�ogaa5oZoyhkMYQLI66nMCt1yAiz1jXmq2MTBxHqtbxBkoJaVsJt0YQMdpkkxwpRpXZHUgur.K9kY4j3vgyG1j44CQPlNsh7mBMxNe5nLdCMjFMy0ufmocRYowg38kMiK9hpFqkFnwYZSZPMGM4wAK5wVvFrwn1phkY3OXr76z5OC5tjNeq3Q--&v=1;
>   path=/; domain=www.yahoo.com Set-Cookie: fpps=deleted; expires=Fri,
>   21-Jan-2011 08:53:09 GMT; path=/; domain=www.yahoo.com Set-Cookie:
>   fpc_s=d=33OMFTGMUw2Z.oeMhzS8DGMizJ2NFSc4VT5QjW6pM.25xOqOYy5nr_kK5C83.tjkxzIiFvBITPc7P5YBehviyRS3piAAliJxvHQHDlbZYOlAdvgPXzJ4zGghf.xEL6Rb6rVdP90xlOc_njpBqlqOcwyMeq0ZqBy2VXuNrIxiD9QjUUsJyfVJ4miF1frSXQOI5Z8MVIErFoBjW3jTQANFu_CayJrjp6RRDc.YG5DCn04SFk3hKALdzVPSyIoawxmicCoWFfN7dvyge8jRoeQXHey.IALpAtcCPlY4eX.teLb.GO0yQxUN5HzgR9I-&v=2;
>   path=/; domain=www.yahoo.com Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Type:
>   text/html;charset=utf-8 Content-Encoding: gzip Age: 2
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive Server: YTS/1.20.0
>
> 000088e ���I�HG8Ae`��t�>#%xc�c#���a��e9��*d��S��@�~}�ZF��~x�
>             6�S8�#ӉO�i:i%��?���a��9rxJ�n���<Q����_�-�A����!D{�{ޱN���f*/h��ΰ ���Ea�h��E��2UY�
>       2�7�����dL>U���^W˳g��H�Q�>���~����iiΟ��@:���R�L�b��K���=�#
>                                                                      Ғ�5���|'�J��eo`��{� Bus error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char buf[501];
...
recv(mySock, buf, 1500, 0)
                  ^^^^
```

If `recv` ever actually reads more than 501 bytes, you'll overflow your buffer, which results in undefined behavior. Make sure you never read more than 501 bytes, or increase your buffer's size.

Also the  `printf`s are not safe. There is nothing that guarantees the input will be proper, `0`-terminated C strings. (You could use `write` and pass the length `recv` returned.)

Comment: But now that I'm not getting that error anymore, how do I read the chunks for the gzip if I want to know the start and end of these packets?

Comment: This is TCP, there is no start/end of packets, just a stream. You will need to parse the headers, and parse the chunked encoding yourself to figure out how much you need to read.

Comment: Read RFC 2616 Section 3.6.1. It explains exactly how `chunked` transfers operate. Each chunk starts with a line of text that specifies how many remaining bytes are in the chunk, and then the  bytes are followed by a CRLF line break. The last chunk has a byte size of 0, and then a set of additional HTTP headers completes the response.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, it looks like you are overrunning `buf`; you declare it as having a length of 501 but then try and read 1500 bytes into it.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't catch that. Thanks, I actually have three different files and I thought I changed all off the 501's to 1500's. It did seem like I was overflowing my buffer, but I wasn't sure how. Your fix worked! Thanks again!